# How to keep AD client-id and client-secret safe for native apps scenario

Tags: oauth-2.0, adal, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

Regarding client-side application scenario (Store Apps, WPF, or WF), which is the best solution to keep our AD client-id and client-secret as safe as possible? I've browsed on the internet and found an information that storing our app secret raw string on the client-side application source code is not very safe, because someone could just decompile our app and run with the client secret. I would like to know the best advice and workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can work around it without compromising security.

Best practice is to use the [oauth2.0 implicit grant flow](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2/grants/implicit.html) where a client secret is not required at all.  Using this flow will return you a short-lived access token (as a URL querystring hash segment) once the user has logged in and granted your app access.